# Check if string has a specific number, not digit

Tags: php, string, find

This is what I have:

```
$a = '3,24,57';

if (strpos($a, '7') == true) {
    echo 'number found';
}
```

The code will return "number found" because of the number 57 but there is no number 7 in the string. How can I make this work in a way that will return true only if the string is like this: "3,7,24,57"

Thanks

Comment: Yeah explode() might be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try like this.

```
$array = explode(",", $a);
if (in_array("7", $array )) {
    echo 'number found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = '3,24,57';

if (strpos($a, ',7,') == true || strpos($a, '7,') == true || strpos($a, ',7') == true) {
    echo 'number found';
}
```

Comment: Well, it also works but I prefer the other ones ;) Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, use the following regex:
Like this:

```
<?php

  $a = '3,24,57';
  $find = 7;
  if (preg_match("/(?<!\d){$find}(?!\d)/", $a)) {
    echo "number found";
  } else {
    echo "number not found";
  }    

?>
```